# Suprimir componentes repetidos java

Tags: java

Estoy intentando añadir a una lista nueva los componentes que no se repiten a partir de la lista original. He realizado este código pero no funciona. Si alguien me puede ayudar....

```
public static <E> IndexedList<E> deleteRepeated(IndexedList<E> l)
{
  IndexedList<E> list = new ArrayIndexedList<E>();
     for(int i=0;i<=l.size();i++) 
     {
        for(int j=0;j<list.size();j++)
        {       
            if(list.get(i).equals(l.get(j)))
            {
                list.removeElementAt(i);
                j=0;
            }
        }
      }
         return list;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo que quieres hacer se resuelve con un java.util.Set. El Set no admite repetidos, con lo cual no tendrias por que remover nada.

Por otro lado si queres seguir usando la lista, podes hacer algo asi:

```
private List<String> removeReated(List<String> originalValues) {
    List<String> newValues = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < originalValues.size(); i++) {
        int repeated = 0;
        if (originalValues.contains(originalValues.get(i))) {
            repeated++;
            if (repeated < 1) {
                newValues.add(originalValues.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
    return newValues;
}
```

EDIT: La solucion correcta es usar un set:

```
Set mySet = new HashSet();
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta!!! podrias mirar [answer] y tambien el [tour]??. se pide que las respuestas sean completas, con ejemplos y todo.

Comment: He modificado mi código pero sigue sin devolverme los número repetidos, he utilizado removeElement en vez de remove pero nada

Comment: @susn tu pregunta dice que queres los que no se repitan. Que es lo que queres?

Comment: Una nueva lista("list") donde los elementos repetidos dentro de "l" han sido borrados.

Answer (score 0):

Usa un set y asegúrate de sobrescribir el método equals en los objetos que pasas al método.

En los dos casos tu. Equals no va a funcionar si no sobrescribes el método equals porque aunque los valores sean los mismos tus objetos son diferentes.

Answer (score 0):

Lo más fácil es a través de `streams`:

```
private List<String> removeReated(List<String> originalValues) {
    return originalValues
        .stream()
        .distinct()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```